# Как вызвать в Ulogin callback

Tags: angularjs, ulogin

Как передать сюда функцию angularjs  из директивы например или из контроллера?
В общем как вызвать в callback ангуляр функцию?

```
 <div  class="text-center"  id="uLogin" data-ulogin="callback=mytest;display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name,email;providers=vkontakte,odnoklassniki,google,yandex,facebook,mailru;hidden=other;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fquest%2Fresource%2Fauth"></div>
```

вот такой же вопрос 
http://ulogin.reformal.ru/proj/?ia=619938

Comment: Что за `ангуляр функция` ?

Comment: любая функция или переменная из angular чтобы он смог увидеть token

Comment: Дак там вроде как и ответ имеется ...

Comment: нет это не ответ, а один из возможных обходов, я так делал, второй вариант отправить ajax через jquery и забрать ангуляром используя что то похожее angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope'); только не особо понимаю как его забзать